# Wav-format different samples

Tags: wav

I'm doing lab work on wav format. Does anyone know where to download different types of files? For example, with a different number of channels or different depths.

I need something like [bmp-suite](http://entropymine.com/jason/bmpsuite/bmpsuite/html/bmpsuite.html)